# numpy: fancy indexing "unexpected behaviour" -- fancy indexing seems to give results that are the "transpose" of what would be expected intuitively

Tags: python, numpy

I am a bit confused about the behaviour of fancy indexing, see:

```
>>> t = np.arange(2*2*3).reshape((2, 2, 3))
>>> t
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
>>> t[1, :, [1, 2]]
array([[ 7, 10],
       [ 8, 11]])
```

I thought that after indexing with `t[1, :, [1, 2]]` I would have had the array:

```
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

but instead I get the tranpose, as can be seen above.

Also, consider the following:

```
>>> t[:, :, [1, 2]][1]
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

This doesn't follow the pattern of behaviour we just noted as being unintuitive...this behaves "as expected". Why?

Why do I get this behaviour, and how can I get the behaviour that I expected?

Comment: This is not fancy indexing, this is [indexing multidimensional arrays using using index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html). Try `t[1, :, 1:3]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Actually, it is fancy indexing, because in my application the array `[1, 2]` is really `[1, 5, 9, 10]`, which, as you can see, is not sequential. I have reduced the complexity of the problem in the "minimum working example" (thus it can be answered with normal sequential indexing notation), but that does not take away from the fact that the problem is *with* fancy indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer),

> In simple cases (i.e. one indexing array
>   and N - 1 slice objects) it does exactly what you would expect (concatenation of
>   repeated application of basic slicing).

In this case, the indexing array is [1, 2], and the slice objects are `1` and `:` (or more precisely, `slice(1,2)`, and `slice(None)`):

So the result is the concatenation of the slices

```
In [43]: t[1,:,1]
Out[43]: array([ 7, 10])

In [44]: t[1,:,2]
Out[44]: array([ 8, 11])
```

Also note that the shape of `t[1, :, [1,2]]` will be (2,2) since the scalar 1
removes the 0 axis and the `:` spans all of axis 1 (which has length 2), and [1,2]
has length 2. So as you run over the last (i.e. second) axis of the result, you get the arrays
`array([ 7, 10])` and `array([ 8, 11])`.

```
In [45]: t[1, :, [1,2]]
Out[45]: 
array([[ 7, 10],
       [ 8, 11]])
```

The easiest way to get the result you want is to use basic slicing,

```
In [45]: t[1, :, 1:3]
Out[45]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

Another way, which uses "fancy" integer indexing is:

```
In [121]: t[1, [(0,0),(1,1)], [1,2]]
Out[121]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

or (using broadcasting)

```
In [154]: t[1, [[0],[1]], [1,2]]
Out[154]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

This might actually be closer to what you want, since it is generalizable to the case where your indexing array is some arbitrary list like `[1, 5, 9, 10]`.

```
In [157]: t = np.arange(2*2*11).reshape(2,2,11)

In [158]: t[1, [[0],[1]], [1,5,9,10]]
Out[158]: 
array([[23, 27, 31, 32],
       [34, 38, 42, 43]])
```

The same rule applies to

```
In [101]: t[:, :, [1, 2]][1]
Out[101]: 
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

First note that the shape of `t[:, :, [1, 2]]` will be (2,2,2). The result will be the concatenation of the basic slices

```
In [102]: t[:, :, 1]
Out[102]: 
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 7, 10]])

In [103]: t[:, :, 2]
Out[103]: 
array([[ 2,  5],
       [ 8, 11]])
```

So as you run over the last (i.e. third) axis of the result, you get the arrays
`array([[ 1,  4], [ 7, 10]])` and `array([[ 2,  5], [ 8, 11]])`.

```
In [107]: np.allclose(t[:, :, [1,2]], np.dstack([np.array([[ 1,  4], [ 7, 10]]), np.array([[ 2,  5], [ 8, 11]])]))
Out[107]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the behavior changes when there's a non-slicing in any previous axes:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.arange(2*2*3).reshape((2, 2, 3))

>>> t[1:2, :, [1, 2]]   # 1 -> 1:2  (slicing)
array([[[ 7,  8],
        [10, 11]]])

>>> t[1][:, [1, 2]]
array([[ 7,  8],
       [10, 11]])
```

Comment: @user89, Sorry, I'm not sure.

Comment: My guess is that `t[1, :, (1, 2)]` gets interpreted the same way as `t[(1, 1), :, (1, 2)]`. That is, indexing `t[1, :, 1]` then `t[1, :, 2]` and joining them along the first axis. This behaviour makes more intuitive sense when using index arrays (i.e. `t[arr]` where arr[0] are the axis 0 indices, arr[1] the axis 1 indices, and so on).